# Querying logins for public role in SQL Server returns unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a program that checks if the user has permissions to read from a linked server on a server. To do this, I check if the user is a member of the 'public' role:

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('public', @login_name)
```

The logins I am querying have 'public' checked on its server roles. However the query only returns 1 if the login also a member of the sysadmin role. If the login only has 'public' checked, it returns 0.

Is this correct behavior? Is this the proper way to check for read permission to a server?

Comment: Are you using SQL authentication or Windows? If Windows, is it explicit logons or are you using groups? I ask because *IS_SRVROLEMEMBER always returns 0 when a Windows group is used as the login argument, and this Windows group is a member of another Windows group which is, in turn, a member of the specified server role.*

Comment: I am using windows authentication. I think I am using explicit logons. For every user, I create them a Login the same as their Windows name. So I don't think I'm passing a group into IS_SRVROLEMEMBER.

Comment: I just tried this with SQL and Windows authentication and couldn't reproduce your issue. I get `1` as result regardless if they are *only* in a public role, or if they are in public *and* sysadmin.

Comment: Did you figure this out--was it user error or?

Comment: Still unresolved. I was able to check that the same query worked for the same users on a different server. So maybe it has to do with a setting on this server.

Comment: it could be orphaned log on's. I'd look into that.